Inner Product of Matrices based on the determinant
Usually the inner product of matrices $A,B\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ is defined to be $\left\langle A,B \right\rangle = \text{tr}(A^\dagger B)$, also know as the Frobenius Inner Product, and this does follow all the inner product properties.
So my question is, why can't we define $\left\langle A,B \right\rangle = \left|\text{det}(A^\dagger B)\right|$?
Is there a problem with the proprieties of inner products, or it just has no application whatsoever?

It doesn't satisfy all the properties of an inner product. Property 3 could perhaps be resolved by defining some equivalence class on the set of matrices, but I see no way for the linearity property to hold.

It's not bilinear!

Also we just have $|\det(A^{\dagger} B)| = |\det A| |\det B|$, so this number isn't really telling us anything about how $A$ and $B$ interact.

@Qiaochu Yuan excellent meta-argumentation.

Thanks Set and Qiaochu Yuan.
That clarifies it all.

Note that $\text{tr}(A^\dagger B) = \sum_{i,j} \bar{A_{ij}} B_{ij}$, so it's really just the usual dot product in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ written in a compact form. So it already has all the nice properties of the dot product (bilinearity, positive definiteness.) This alternative won't inherit those properties.
